# How do I handle modified/editied cell value at client side for float values in dojo

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have an editable cell which contain decimal value for example 2.123456 (6 place after decimal). I want to show 6 place after decimal after user edit the cell(let say user enters 2.123 then I want to show 2.123000) and restrict editing upto 6 place after dacimal.

I am new in dojo. Please help my in identifying solution.

Is there any even which can tell me that cell is edited so that I can fetch modified value and apply logic and then set it again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather old, but I stumbled upon it while looking for an answer myself.  Documenting an answer for posterity.

You should consider using a custom formatter:
http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojox/grid/DataGrid#formatting-a-date-field

Then inside your custom formatter you can apply whatever formatting to numbers and strings that you wish.